# Is size_t only in C++ standard or C standard as well?

Tags: c++, c, size-t

Is size_t only in C++ standard or C standard as well?

I cannot find a C header in the "/usr/include" tree that defines size_t.

If it is not in the C std, is GCC just doing some magic to make things work?

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: Why do you think this should be in /usr/include?

Comment: Neil is right, you're looking it the wrong place. C++ headers are in /usr/include/c++/${gcc-version}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C99 draft:

**7.17 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**

1. The following types and macros are defined in the standard header `<stddef.h>`. Some
   are also defined in other headers, as noted in their respective subclauses.
2. The types are [-*snip*-]

   ```
   size_t
   ```

   which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator; [-*snip*-]

Comment: The "other headers" part applies to `size_t`, it's also declared in `<stdlib.h>` (see 7.20/2).

Answer (score 5):

`size_t` is defined in both `<stddef.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 2):

size_t is from the C standard library

It is declared in

```
#include <stddef.h>  //For C
#include <cstddef>   //For C++
```

Answer (score 1):

$ `grep -R -P "typedef.*\s+size_t;" /usr/include/ 2> /dev/null`

will give you a list of files that define size_t

Answer (score 0):

size_t is in [stdlib.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdlib.h#size_t) for C (or cstdlib.h in C++).

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in string.h in ansi c.